# flutter in_app_purchase queryProductDetails can't find one of the purchases if too many queries

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm following [Google's IAP tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases)

I've set up two consumable products: consume1, consume2; and two subscriptions: test, test2

```dart
const ids = <String>{
      'test',
      'test2',
      'consume1',
      'consume2',
    };
final response = await iapConnection.queryProductDetails(ids);

for (var element in response.notFoundIDs) {
  debugPrint('Purchase $element not found');
}
for (var element in response.productDetails) {
  debugPrint(
      '${element.id}, ${element.title}, ${element.description}, ${element.price}');
}
```

For the code above I got the output

```
I/flutter ( 4708): Purchase test2 not found
I/flutter ( 4708): consume1, consume purchase test 1, $33.49
I/flutter ( 4708): consume2, consume test 2, $4.12
I/flutter ( 4708): test, test, $1.00
```

it appears that it couldn't find the product id `test2`

then I found out as long as the number of elements in `ids` >= 4, one of the ids won't be found,

if it's less than 4, all the products will be found normally

Can anyone explain?